# Why does a map only job in hive results in a single output file

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

When I execute the following query, I get only one file as output although I have 8 mappers and 0 reducers.

```
create table table_2 as select * from table_1.
```

8 mappers are invoked and there is no reducer phase. 
There is just only one file in the location of table_2, shouldn't there be 8 files as we have 8 mappers and 0 reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hive documentation, [Configuration Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)...

> `hive.merge.mapfiles`
>    Default Value: `true`
>     *Merge small files at the end of a map-only job.*
>
> `hive.merge.tezfiles`
>     Default Value: `false`
>     *Merge small files at the end of a Tez DAG*
>
> `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize`
>    Default Value:
>   `16000000`
>    *When the average output file size of a job
>   is less than this number,
>   Hive will start an additional map-reduce job
>   to merge the output files into bigger files...*

So, if *(a)* your test dataset is very small and *(b)* you don't use TEZ but plain old MapReduce, then Hive will run a post-Map step just to merge the (intermediate) results, by default.

Whereas it would not happen after a Reduce step, unless you force `hive.merge.mapredfiles` to `true`.