# How to get one file in Hive

Tags: hive

I tried a Hive process,
which generate words frequency rank from
sentences,
I would like to output not multiple files but
one file.

I searched the similar question this web site,
I found mapred.reduce.tasks=1,
but  it didn't generate one file but 50 files.

The process l tried has 50 input files and
they are all gzip file.

How do I get one merged file?
50 input files size is so large that I suppose the
reason may be some kind of limit.

Comment: `mapred.reduce.tasks=1` didn't work probably because you don't have reduce jobs. you can induce reduce jobs by adding for example `sort by` to your Hive query

Comment: What is the reason in generating one file? Is because your program is fully distributed, each container creates it's own file independently. Single reducer will kill parallelism. Later you can also read them in parallel. Hive table also can read many files in it's location. You can concatenate them using cat command, better do not use zip to make this easier

Comment: Check Hive properties under "merge small files" _(where "small" is configurable)_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272492/why-does-a-map-only-job-in-hive-results-in-a-single-output-file

Answer (score 1):

in your job use **Order By** clause with some field.

So that hive will enforce to run only one reducer as a result you are going to end up with one file has created in the HDFS.

```
hive> Insert into default.target 
         Select * from default.source
      order by id;
```

For more details regards to order by clause refer to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SortBy#LanguageManualSortBy-SyntaxofOrderBy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715044/hive-cluster-by-vs-order-by-vs-sort-by) links.

Comment: Really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind answers,
you are really saving me.
I am trying order by,
but it is taking much time,
i am waiting for it.
All I have to do is get one file 
to make output file into input of 
the next step,
I am also going to try simply cat all files from reducer outputs according to the advice,
if I will do it, I am worried that files are unique and does not have any the same word between files , and  whether it is normal gzip file made by catting multiple gzip files.